# Снятие запрета на клик в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Я использую функцию `.off('click')` чтобы клик по кнопке не тригернулся. Но как потом вернуть возможность клика, чтобы

```
$('#element').on('click', function() { });
```

заработал?

Answer (score 5):

Функция [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) не предотвращает генерацию события, а удаляет обработчик события. Соответственно, чтобы "вернуть возможность клика" необходимо снова назначить обработчик события:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(){})
```

---

Когда логика приложения предполагает периодическое отключение и включение обработки событий, сложность представляет удалить конкретный обработчик события и оставить другие обработчики (о которых мы можем даже не знать).
Чтобы решить эту задачу, есть следующие возможности.

#### Удаление с помощью указание обработчика

У функции `.off` есть перегрузка

```
.off( events [, selector ], handler )
```

которая позволяет отключать конкретную функцию-обработчик, что позволяет удобно отключать и подключать обработку события:

```
$('#element').on('click', handler);  // назначаем обработчик события `click` на элементе
$('#element').off('click', handler); // удаляем конкретный обработчик
$('#element').on('click', handler);  // вновь установим тот же обработчик
```

Однако у этого решения есть минус:

> При удалении конкретных обработчиков (когда задан параметр `handler`) следует быть осторожным, если при их установке использовалась `$.proxy()` или подобные механизмы. Это связанно с тем, что для удаления конкретных обработчиков, jQuery сравнивает специфические id функций, которые будут совпадать для функций, созданных с помощью `$.proxy()`. В связи с этим, с элементов могут быть удалены обработчики, которые вы не планировали удалять.

[Источник](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Off)

#### Удаление с помощью пространства имен

Пространство имен задается через точку после типа события: `'click.myPlugin'`.
Если при назначении обработчика, мы использовали пространства имен, мы можем безопасно удалить свой обработчик, не затронув другие обработчики:

```
$('#element').on('click.myPlugin', handler); // назначаем обработчик на событие `click` с пространством имен `myPlugin`
$('#element').off('click.myPlugin'); // удаляем все обработчики событие `click` с пространством имен `myPlugin`
// или 
$('#element').off('.myPlugin') // удаляем обработчики всех типов событий с пространством имен `.myPlugin`
```

Comment: Лучше отключать по namespace'у, чем по обработчику. Был с этим у меня косяк когда-то.

Comment: @Qwertiy обновил ответ... Хотя вторая часть, наверное, не на заданный вопрос отвечает, а на какой-то другой.

Comment: Круто! Про $.proxy даже не знал. У меня другая проблема была - обработчик вызывался после отписки один раз (он там срабатывал в рамках того же клика), а namespace'ы эту проблему решили :)